# My cryptic bookshelf

Tags: pattern, knowledge

I have a cryptic bookshelf that I keep fiction books in. However, some of them are lost, and I don't know which ones go where!

> **Shelf One:**
>   *The Lightning Thief* by Rick Riordan
>   *Thunder and Shadow* by Erin Hunter
>   [MISSING]
>   *School of Fear* by Gitty Daneshvari
>   *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets* by J.K. Rowling
>
> **Shelf Two:**
>   *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban* by J.K. Rowling
>   [MISSING]
>   [MISSING]
>   *Prince Caspian* by C.S. Lewis
>   *School of Fear: Class is Not Dismissed!* by Gitty Daneshvari
>
> **Shelf Three:**
>   [MISSING]
>   *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire* by J.K. Rowling
>   *The Titan's Curse* by Rick Riordan
>   [MISSING]
>   [MISSING]

Quick! I need to order new books to fill in the holes! Can you please remind me which books go where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that your bookshelves contain

> titles from several popular children/YA book series:
>
> - *Percy Jackson and the Olympians* (Rick Riordan)
> - *Warriors: A Vision of Shadows* (Erin Hunter)
> - *The Chronicles of Narnia* (C.S. Lewis)
> - *School of Fear* (Gitty Daneshvari)
> - *Harry Potter* (J.K. Rowling)

And to fill the shelves, you

> put the first or second book of each series in the order as above for Shelf 1, then with each subsequent shelf you put the last book of the previous shelf first (shifting everything else one space right) and replace each book with the next one in the series it belongs to. The *Harry Potter* books follow this rule, and so do the *Percy Jackson* and *School of Fear* books partially.

Thus, you should order the following books marked in bold and place them in this order:

> **Shelf 1**
>  1. *The Lightning Thief*
>  2. *Thunder and Shadow*
>  3. ***The Lion, the Witch, and the Wardrobe*** (first book of *Chronicles of Narnia*)
>  4. *School of Fear*
>  5. *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*
>
>  **Shelf 2**
>  1. *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*
>  2. ***The Sea of Monsters*** (second book of *Percy Jackson*)
>  3. ***Shattered Sky*** (third book of *Warriors*)
>  4. *Prince Caspian*
>  5. *School of Fear: Class is Not Dismissed!*
>
>  **Shelf 3**
>  1. ***School of Fear: The Final Exam*** (third book of *School of Fear*)
>  2. *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*
>  3. *The Titan's Curse*
>  4. ***Darkest Night*** (fourth book of *Warriors*)
>  5. ***The Voyage of the Dawn Treader*** (third book of *Chronicles of Narnia*)

Comment: Taken from google search, but down to personal opinion, I only know this as I recently brought the complete collection from a local charity shop: Rot13 `Gur Zntvpvna'f Arcurj jnf jevggra frireny lrnef nsgre P. F. Yrjvf svefg ortna Gur Puebavpyrf bs Aneavn, ur jnagrq vg gb or ernq nf gur svefg obbx va gur frevrf. Unecre Pbyyvaf vf unccl gb cerfrag gurfr obbxf va gur beqre va juvpu Cebsrffbe Yrjvf cersreerq.` But your answer mataches the original question, so it may be that the original question has an error.

Comment: @5202456: Rot13 `V xarj vg unq gb or pbzvat orpnhfr bs gur gjb qvssrerag beqrevatf bs gur Puebavpyrf bs Aneavn. V qryvorengryl pubfr gur choyvpngvba beqre orpnhfr gung'f jung Jvxvcrqvn unf yvfgrq (pheeragyl).`